# Open the list of SMS messages on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, sms

In an app I'm creating I want to open the Messages app, showing the list of received messages. I know I can open the app to create an sms with this code:

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "sms:") {
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    }
}
```

This will open the messages app, but with a blank new message. Is there any way to just launch the messages app and show the received messages?

- I don't want to access them
- Apple documentation for [sms url scheme](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/SMSLinks/SMSLinks.html) states the scheme is `sms:`
- I don't want to send one using the [MFMessageComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/) class
- For mail I can do `let url = NSURL(string: "message://")` and that just open the mail app

*Here's my usecase: During registration I'm sending a verification text using TextMagic. I want to add a button on the screen to help the user open his/her Messages App.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in iOS 11 it works as expected.

```
    if let url = URL(string: "sms:") {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
```

This will open the sms app and show the messages page.

Comment: I'll have to check for iOS 12, will do soon.

Comment: Did you figure it out? It shows **new message** in iOS 13.

Comment: Never did, the project ended, so haven't looked at iOS 12 / 13.

Answer (score 1):

You can see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/SMSLinks/SMSLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH7-SW1) that the sms scheme url doesn't provide the possibility to add a body like the for the mail.

To achieve your goal you should use `MFMessageComposeViewController`.

Comment: I don't want to create or send a message. I just want the messages app to open and not show a blank new text message.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to figure this out for myself on iOS 16.  On a whim, I tried `messages://` as the URL, and it worked perfectly ... with the catch that it brings me back to the same place in the app I left off, whether that's the message list or an open conversation, just like switching apps.